# How to reload a jquery Datatable after the user finished editing operation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using `ASP.NET MVC4`. I want to refresh my table after a user has edited a column.(I do not want to make it like when a user press enter, I want to refresh it when a user finishes writing and clicks somewhere else.This is my `jquery` script :

```
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#result').dataTable().makeEditable();

        });
     </script>
```

And this is my controller:

```
     public string UpdateData(string id,string value, int columnPosition)
    {
        ObjectId oid = new ObjectId(id);
        var query = from n in ObjectMongoCollection.AsQueryable<User>()

                    where n.UserId == oid
                    select n;

        User user = query.FirstOrDefault();
        if (user == null)
        {
           return "error";
        }
        else
        {
            if (columnPosition == 0)
            {
                user.Name = value.Trim();
            }
            else if (columnPosition == 1)
            {
                user.Surname = value.Trim();
            }
            else
            {
                user.Number = value.Trim();
            }
            ObjectMongoCollection.Save(user);
            return "successfull";

        }
    }
```

I do not know which function should I use and where to put this function on my code. (I do not know why but fnDraw method does not work) Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#result').dataTable().makeEditable();
              $('#element').keyup(function(e) {
                if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                  location.reaload();
                }
              });
                 if($('#element').click()) {
                   location.reaload();
              }
                 if($('#element2').click()) {
                   location.reaload();
              }

        });
```

This method takes an optional parameter (true \ false), true means reload from the server rather from the cache, the default is false, meaning by default it uses the web browser's cache.

**Edit**:

Notice that 13 checks if enter key was pressed, number 13 = enter key.

Comment: It does not work. It changes the data in database but not reloading the page with new data.

Comment: omg actually it refreshes the page continuesly  :) it never stops.

Comment: There you go, because it's on document ready.. expected as much, just stuff a condition and you're ok here :)

Comment: Well, what kind of condition should I write?. As I said I want to refresh it not only after pressing enter but also clicking another column or row in table.

Comment: It does not work. I checked with the alert but the code does not enter in if statement. I also do not get the #element keyword. What does it mean?Is it default or should I change it?

Comment: '#' stands for ID. meaning, instead of element, use the ID of your element for example $('#myButton'); stands for a button with the ID of myButton.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formate

> $('#myTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();